# Scifi novel with scientist studying 'celestial statues'. His daughter has a sexual relationship with a robot

Tags: story-identification, novel, robots

About 10 years ago, I read a sci-fi book in French. I am hoping the book exist in English as well.

The action starts in a spaceship. A scientist is studying "*celestial statues*" that were thought to be without movement, until they found they were very slowly moving.

His daughter is in the ship as well, and bored. She starts playing sexual game with a robot, which acquires AI (artificial intelligence) points this way. When the father discovers it, he want to kill the robot, but he has enough AI to be considered to be as human.

The daughter denounces her father and calls the AI "darling" ("chéri" in French) in a joke. Then my memory becomes a blur. They are other characters, one is named "*The Bird*" ("L'oiseau"). It is quite surreal!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it was "[Evolution's Darling](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24771.Evolution_s_Darling)" by Scott Westerfeld .

> She peered at the statue for a solid, unblinking minute. Protesting
>   tears gathered to blur her vision, but Rathere's gaze did not waver.
>   Another minute, and a tic tugged at one eye, taking up the steady
>   rhythm of her heartbeat.
>
> She kept watching.
>
> "Ha!" she finally proclaimed. "I saw it move."
>
> "Where?" asked a voice in her head, unconvinced.
>
> Rathere rubbed her eyes with the heels of her hands, mouth open,
>   awestruck by the shooting red stars behind her eyelids. Her blinks
>   made up now for the lost minutes, and she squinted at the dusty town
>   square.
>
> "His foot," she announced, "it moved. But maybe... only a centimeter."

Comment: Can you please provide some details about the story, including the author and a synopsis, so that future people looking for this story can identify it?